# Preloading my audio file in html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently using the below way to play sound effect on my website. I need the sound to play out everytime I received a protocol from my slave device:

```
<script>
function RxProtocol()
{
    playSound('audio123.wav');
}

function playSound(soundfile) 
{
    document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
    "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
</script>

<body>
<span id="dummy"></span>
</body>
```

But seems like this way the audio played is delayed everytime. After I received my protocol for 2 seconds, the audio only played.

Is it because I did not preload my audio? Could you guys teach me how to modify my code and make it into preload enable?

Comment: I don't think you can preload audio files. What is the code calling `RxProtocol()`? Maybe the delay is in there.

Comment: Is it? But I a search from online I find that there's a preload attribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_preload.asp. But I don't know how to use it...

Comment: That's part of HTML5, assumed you wanted code that works for older browsers as well.

Comment: Is it that using my code above, it is impossible there is a delay?

Comment: Like I said, the delay might be in whatever code that is calling `RxProtocol()` function. If you don't want to post it then fine, but we can't possibly help you further here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `preload attribute` of `html5 audio tag`

like `preload="auto"`

also read http://webdesignledger.com/tips/audio-and-video-with-html5 and http://code.google.com/p/html5-preloader/

Comment: But I'm not using the audio tag =(

Comment: I think its not possible in `embed`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436633/preload-mp3-file-before-using-the-play-button

Answer (score 0):

Somehow my below coding worked for firefox and chrome but not for IE9:

```
<script>
function RxProtocol()
 {
    var a = document.getElementById("audio1");
    a.play();
 }

</script>

<body>
<audio id="audio1">
<source src="audio.wav" type="audio/wav">
<source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
audio tag not supported.
</audio>
</body>
```

After trying and trying, I found out that I need to put the below in order for IE9 to work. Firefox and Chrome worked too:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Before this, I put the below coding which worked on Firefox and Chrome only:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
```

Do you guys know what is the difference of these two meta?